# Laravel : run specific middleware after Auth middleware

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

I've created a middleware that should be run for **every** request  so i added that to `$middleware` property of `Http\Kernel` . I've also used `Auth::check()` inside this middleware , so my middleware should be run **after** `Auth` middleware unless `Auth::check()` will not work, how should i do that?

Comment: Did you find a way?

Answer (score -2):

As far as i understand, you have already do that.

You should put your code into `Auth::check()` statement like below:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Test
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            // your logic here

        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Auth::check()` wont run , because my middleware is processing **before** `Auth` middleware,so your code does not work too if it is in `$middleware` property of `Http\Kernel`